# How to call react context update function in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to use react context to store global variables for my react application. I'm using all class components with no functional components.  I have a login form where the user enters their email and password and I would like to store the email as a global variable using context.  Here is my UserContext File below.

```
import React from "react";
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
export default UserContext;
```

Then in my app.js I have this set up:

```
class App extends Component {
  handleLoggedIn = (username) => {
    console.log("getting user: " + username);
    const user = { name: "deffy" };
    this.setState({ currentUser: user });
  };
  state = { currentUser: { name: null } };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Nav />
        <div className="mainContent">
          <Switch>
            <UserContext.Provider
              value={{
                currentUser: this.state.currentUser,
                onLoggedIn: this.handleLoggedIn,
              }}
            >
              <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
              <Route path="/inventory" component={Inventory} />
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            </UserContext.Provider>
```

Finally in my login page I try to update the value for the name variable using the onLoggedIn function but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.  I have a doSubmit function where I call the onLoggedIn:

```
 doSubmit = () => {
    const { userList, data } = this.state;
    for (let x in userList) {
      if (
        data.email === userList[x].email &&
        data.password === userList[x].password
      ) {
        UserContext.onLoggedIn(userList[x].email);
      }
    }
  };
```

This only should change the value of the context name variable if the input for email and password matches the database pair.  I also have this bit of code right after the class component.

```
static contextType = UserContext;
```

Any help would be really appreciated!